# How to solve dependency issue of CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll?

Tags: .net, vb.net, crystal-reports, business-objects

i've created a project in vb.net 2013 using crystal report CRforVS_13_0_24. On my side in warning secion error prompt "Unable to find dependency 'BUSINESSOBJECTS.LICENSING.KEYCODEDECODER' (Signature='692FBEA5521E1304' Version='13.0.2000.0') of assembly 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll'". while on client side this error occurs while showing report.
any one can help me to solve and fix this issue.

Comment: Please provide more details: more code snippets or even a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

You should install the appropriate [SAP Crystal Reports Redistributable module](https://help.sap.com/viewer/0d6684e153174710b8b2eb114bb7f843/SP21/en-US/45b285716e041014910aba7db0e91070.html)